# Is there a way to add a custom text + link above search results for different searches?

Tags: search

Do any of you know a way to customize what displays on a search result page for different individual searches? I am open to doing this through code, a free plugin, or a premium plugin.

Context: I run a small college's Wordpress website. Sometimes users search for something that is on another site. Example: If someone searches for "athletics," I need to be able to point them to our non-Wordpress athletics site. I would like to be able to add "Visit our athletics site (link)" to the search page, but only when the query is "athletics."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with if-condition, example:

```
if( get_search_query() == 'athletics' ){
    echo 'Visit our athletics site';
}
```